# Help with Makefile: No rule to make target

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall

RM = /bin/rm -rf
BIN_DIR = 

ifeq "$(DEBUG)" "1"
BIN_DIR = Debug
else
BIN_DIR = Release
endif

OBJS = \
$(BIN_DIR)/Unit.o

$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    @echo Building "$@"
    @g++ -c "$<" -o"$@"

all: $(OBJS)
clean:
    $(RM) $(BIN_DIR)

.PHONY: all clean
```

However, when I try to build my project this, it gives me the error:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/Unit.o', needed by 'all'. Stop.`

I am new to writing makefiles from scratch and so this might be a stupid question, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you have `src/Unit.c` from where you run `make`?

Comment: Yes. The `src` folder is at the same level as the Makefile, and the Unit.c file is in there.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. That is not the issue though. It was just my mistake when typing in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    @echo Building "$@"
    @g++ -c "@<" -o"$@"
```

I think that's more like this :

```
$(BIN_DIR)%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. The @< was only a typo in my question, I actually had "$<" in my Makefile. What else changed?

Comment: But how do `make` and `cc` know that the source code is in *src* rather than in *Release* or *Debug*?

Comment: I copied over the code he has here, and added the src/ and it worked. Which is why I can't figure out what else changed. But it worked. For now, satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

As Sean Bright already pointed out, changing

```
@g++ -c "@<" -o"$@"
```

to

```
@g++ -c "$<" -o"$@"
```

also makes the Makefile work for me (ming32-make: GNU Make 3.81)

Since you had the Makefile on the same level as the source file (inside the `src` directory), your rule were failing.